# Where are all the locations of the Aether Foundation members in Pokémon moon?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

Pokémon moon, the 3DS version, it's the same as ultra moon, just different devices.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [employees list](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Aether_Foundation_Employee_(Trainer_class)#Pok.C3.A9mon_Sun_and_Moon) and their Pokemon's levels, they seem all located in the Aether Paradise.

[Lusamine](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Lusamine) and [Faba](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Faba) are also found there.
It's worth noting that Faba can also be challenged

> for the title of Champion at the Pokémon League.